# How can Norwegian Customs know who repaired their boats abroad?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, norway, sea-travel

I read in [this article](https://www.aftenposten.no/norge/i/b5AxV3/tolletaten-med-storaksjon-i-oslofjorden-og-langs-soerlandskysten?) as well as [this](https://fredrikstadavisa.no/2019/06/13/tolletaten-gjennomforte-storaksjon-pa-sjoen-reperasjon-i-utlandet/) and [this](https://www.nrk.no/sorlandet/tror-batfolk-unndrar-seg-moms-1.11883959) (all in Norwegian, so use Google Translate), that Norwegian Customs control private boats (owned by individuals) coming from abroad, to see if they repaired their boats abroad. The reason for that is that people are supposed to pay tax to Norway for the repair they performed on the boats abroad.

How can the Norwegian Customs ascertain whether a boat was repaired abroad? Let us say that I have a leisure both in terrible condition. I sail my boat down to Poland, where I repair it into tip-top shape for much cheaper than what the cost would have been in Norway. I then sail back to Norway, and upon returning to Norway, customs stop my boat. They can obviously see that my boat is in tip-top condition, but how can they know the boat was in bad condition when i left Norway? How can they know it was not in tip-top condition all along, or repaired in Norway before I left? I may have repaired it myself, or kept it continually maintained, for all they know.

Comment: Are you sure that you understood that article correctly? It seems an odd piece of taxation, precisely because of the difficulty of enforcing it.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass Yeah, I am sure. Here is another article that confirms it: https://www.nrk.no/sorlandet/tror-batfolk-unndrar-seg-moms-1.11883959

Comment: The Norwegian tax authorities would know if the boat owner is not able to present an invoice from a Norwegian boatyard.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica How can they know the boat wasn't in good condition all along? Or that the owner didn't simply repair it themselves?

Comment: If you repair it yourself yiu will have invoices or bills of sale for the parts and paints used. And any boat needs regular upkeep, any boat owner should have proof of their latest paint job at least.

Comment: You do not sail a boat in poor condition to Poland, you might put it on a trailer and drive it. Using ferries. Sea is dangerous.

Comment: @Willeke Possibly. For example, a boat may have both sails and an engine, and you used the engine to get to Poland, then repaired the sails. Point taken about invoices for parts though.

Comment: @RevetahwsaysReinstateMonica do you sail/use a boat on sea? Motor failure between say Sweden and Poland would be very dangerous. Most boat owners will only try such with sail back-up, or only sail with motor back-up.

Comment: Repairs needed while abroad are not unlikely but should not be in the 'complete overhaul' categorie.

Comment: Some repairs need some paperwork. I don't know about boats, but changing the engine in a car or an airplane would be documented in the vehicle papers which, for cars, include engine block number.

Comment: They can always ask you, and you have to decide: Do you want to pay the tax, or do you risk being caught for tax evasion, which is criminal, you’ll pay the fine, and the tax for their _estimate_ of the repair bill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If some parts look newer or the boat is in a much better shape than expected based on age, they can demand to see invoices and details of where and when the boat was serviced. If you cannot document the boat maintenance history (which might also be desirable or even mandatory for other reasons) or produce invoices for parts and material, that could be enough to initiate a procedure.

It's the way customs enforcement work in other domains too (consider someone travelling with valuable jewelry or clothes that feel new). It doesn't aim at stopping each and every case but mostly at deterrence (and collecting money) and rules of evidence are lighter or even reversed compared to criminal procedures. I don't know about Norway specifically but typically that would mean that they don't have to positively prove (“beyond a reasonable doubt”) that you had work done abroad. It's enough if they prove that is looks likely that work has been done and then demand when and where it was done. It's then up to *you* to disprove their assumptions.